# How to get buttons to the end of material ui list and checkbox to the start of the list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My css is not very good and I am facing a lot of difficulties with that... I am trying to make a react todo app with the help of material-ui... My problem is I want to show todo items in material-ui list, where in the list 1) first item will be checkbox 2) second todo text 3) third edit and delete buttons

[image]

**code for rendering mui list**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { todoDeleted, todoUpdated, todoCompleted } from '../Slices/TodoSlice';
import { Button, Checkbox, List, ListItem, ListItemSecondaryAction, ListItemText, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  listRoot: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fce4ec',
    borderWidth: "1px",
    borderColor: "#aaaaaa",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderRadius: "20px",
    height: "35px",
    margin: "5px 5px"
  },
  item: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: "500px"
  }
})

export default function TodoItem({ todo, i }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState(todo.text);

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    dispatch(
      todoUpdated({
        id: todo.id,
        text,
      })
    );

    if (edit) {
      setText(todo.text);
    }
    setEdit(!edit);
  };

  return (
      <div className={classes.listRoot}>
        <List>
          <ListItem className={classes.item}>
        
        <ListItemText>
          {todo.done ? (
            <p>
              <del>{todo.text}</del>
            </p>
          ) : (
            <h4>
              {edit ? (
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={text}
                  value={text}
                  onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
                />
              ) : (
                todo.text
              )}
            </h4>
          )}
        </ListItemText>
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <Checkbox
          value={todo.id}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(todoCompleted(+e.target.value))}
          defaultChecked={todo.done}
        />
        <button
          variant="contained" color="primary" edge='end'
          onClick={() => handleUpdate()}
          disabled={todo.done}
        >
          {edit ? 'Update' : 'Edit'}
        </button>
        <button
          variant="contained" color="primary"
          onClick={() => dispatch(todoDeleted(todo.id))}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
        </List>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I want first item as checkbox, second todo text and third buttons, please guide me

Comment: Please provide a repro so we can work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your [edited CopePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-sun-rhw16?file=/src/components/TodoList.js) and here is the main code that I modified :

TodoList.js :

```
import { makeStyles, List } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  rootDiv: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginLeft: "10px",
    marginRight: "10px"
  },
  p: {
    fontSize: "30px",
    fontweight: "bolder"
  }
});

export default function TodoList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.TodoReducer);
  const filter = useSelector((state) => state.viewFilterReducer);

  const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
    switch (filter) {
      case "SHOW_ALL":
        return todos;
      case "SHOW_ACTIVE":
        return todos.filter((todo) => !todo.done);
      case "SHOW_COMPLETED":
        return todos.filter((todo) => todo.done);
      default:
        return todos;
    }
  };
  const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(todos, filter);

  return (
    <div className={classes.rootDiv}>
      {visibleTodos?.length === 0 ? (
        <p className={classes.p}>No Todo Item Here</p>
      ) : (
        <List>
          {/*
            I moved the list here, because you need to create only one list 
            and loop over you items  
          */}
          {visibleTodos.map((todo, i) => (
            <TodoItem key={i} todo={todo} />
          ))}
        </List>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

TodoItem.js :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { todoDeleted, todoUpdated, todoCompleted } from "../Slices/TodoSlice";
import {
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemSecondaryAction,
  ListItemText,
  ListItemIcon,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

/* 
Since we fixed the issue about displaying multiple <List>,
you only need to style the items.
You can now properly define the height of your items, and set whatever you want as style,
the default flex layout is kept
*/
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  item: {
    height: "35px",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fce4ec",
    border: "1px solid #aaaaaa",
    borderRadius: "20px",
    margin: "5px 5px"
  }
});

export default function TodoItem({ todo, i }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState(todo.text);

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    dispatch(
      todoUpdated({
        id: todo.id,
        text
      })
    );

    if (edit) {
      setText(todo.text);
    }
    setEdit(!edit);
  };

  return (
    <ListItem className={classes.item}>
      <Checkbox
        value={todo.id}
        onChange={(e) => dispatch(todoCompleted(+e.target.value))}
        defaultChecked={todo.done}
      />
      <ListItemText>
        {todo.done ? (
          <p>
            <del>{todo.text}</del>
          </p>
        ) : (
          <h4>
            {edit ? (
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={text}
                value={text}
                onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
              />
            ) : (
              todo.text
            )}
          </h4>
        )}
      </ListItemText>
      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          edge="end"
          onClick={() => handleUpdate()}
          disabled={todo.done}
        >
          {edit ? "Update" : "Edit"}
        </button>
        <button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => dispatch(todoDeleted(todo.id))}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

I mainly changed the following things :

1. Moved the `<List>` component in the parent. You were creating a list for each item, which were creating multiple CSS problems. Pay attention to what your component is supposed to display !
2. Removed the CSS `listRoot` and the `div` node as well. It's not needed anymore
3. Moved the checkbox as the first child of the listItem so it respect the order you asked for

---

The layout has its own padding value. I can only HIGHLY advice you to keep it as it is since it's clean, but if you really want to center your items'content, you can still add paddings to you list items and second element, something like :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  item: {
    // ...
  },
  itemSpacing: { padding: 0 25% }
});
```

And then:

```
<ListItem className={[classes.item, classes.itemSpacing]}>
```

and :

```
<ListItemSecondaryAction className={classes.itemSpacing}>
```

But be really carefull, it will break if your item text is too long, 1) because you set a hard coded height to the item, and 2) because `ListItemSecondaryAction` is in `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you'll add the css file - therefore we can check the current status.

But anyway, have a look at CSS grid layout. This could be the right thing for you.
With CSS grid layout your able to assign an grid position to an element for e.g. checkbox 1.
Then you can select with `display: grid` that id 1 should be displayed first and so on.

Comment: can you show that a little bit by code. please

Comment: It's already designed with flexbox, there's no point in adding grid here. Something in his css is breaking hte layout.

Comment: without flexbox listitems was weird outside of the list

Comment: @sultan Yes, but it's most probably because your code is breaking the default flex behaviour. Add a repro on stackblitz or codepen so we can work on it

Comment: @QuentinGrisel please check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hertz-swe2e?file=/package.json)